# Effective ways to discipline my 5 year old

Tags: discipline

My five year old can be challenging at times. She just started kindergarten this year and has improved with her behavior some, but still makes bad decisions that she knows better than to make. She can be disrespectful to adults at her school and think nothing of it. I don't understand! She is very strong willed and confident and maybe a little too confident at times! Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi Leslie, and welcome to the site. Have you searched "discipline"? There is a lot of information available, and reading some of the questions/answers might not only give you some answers, but might also help you narrow down your question to help with your particular situation (e.g. what you've tried that others have suggested, and what hasn't worked, etc.)

Comment: This is incredibly broad - could you give us more information to work with, please?

Answer (score 1):

In general, kids are often looking to test boundaries of grab attention.

So two basic principles are 1) to establish transparently clear  boundaries, as in listing a very short, limited set of words that are not acceptable at home; and 2) to keep emotions and attention to the minimum in response to behavior you want to limit and instead reward good behavior.

You can also let her be in charge of herself and ask her to find herself, be proud of herself, be better than before, the best she can. This type of 'ownership' of her own behavior might put it in a different perspective.

Otherwise, there's a 'character development' set of tools that can be useful: 
 there's books, cards, etc. with short stories about honor, respect, patience, perseverance, teamwork, etc and how they are valuable.